# login for the branchAdmin using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]I am trying that i want to login as Branch Admin with the branch email and password and the function which i make for the ("Normal User") authentication in (" AuthController ") and the function work correctly for the User. I can Copy this function and Paste in (" BranchController ") with the required changes according to branch Which i use the Email & Password of branch and login as BranchAdmin but the function does'not work correctly.

BranchController:

```
public function authenticateBranchAdmin(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->passes()){
        if(Auth::attempt([
            'email' =>  $request->email,
            'password'  =>  $request->password,
        ])){
            if(Auth::branch()->email === $request->email){
                return redirect('/branch/'.Auth::branch()->id);
            }

        }else{
            if($this->AdminIsVerified($request->email)){
                $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid email or password');
            }
            return redirect('/Admin/login');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('/Admin/login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}

protected function AdminIsVerified($email){
    return Branch::where('email','=', $email)->count();
}

public function getBranch($id){
    if($this->isUserBranchOwner($id)){
        $branch = Branch::find($id);
        return view('branch')->with('branch', $branch);
    }else{
        return redirect('/branch/'.$this->getUserBranchId());
    }
}

public function isUserBranchOwner($id){
    return Branch::where('id','=', Auth::branch()->id)->where('id', '=', $id)->count();
}

protected function getUserBranchId(){
    return Branch::where('id','=', Auth::branch()->id)->first()->id;
}
```

}

AuthController:

```
public function authenticateUser(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->passes()){
        if(Auth::attempt([
            'email' =>  $request->email,
            'password'  =>  $request->password,
            'verified'  =>  1
        ])){
            if(Auth::user()->type === 'User'){
                $request->session()->flash('message', 'Successfull');
            }
            return redirect('/profile');
        }else{
            if($this->userIsVerified($request->email)){
                $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid email or password');
            }else{
                $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid email, password or unverified account');
            }
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}

protected function userIsVerified($email){
    return User::where('email','=', $email)->where('verified', 1)->count();
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: See this error. I will also change the Authentication in the auth.file

Comment: So what `Auth::branch()` should do?

Comment: go to branch table and check the email and password exist.

Comment: This is not a built-in laravel  implementation, right?

Comment: Except Auth.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142357/discussion-between-haider-and-amr-aly).